# Having trouble with "simple math"

Tags: cobol

I have an assignment where ?I need to take a gross pay that is paid in cash and display how many 100s,50s,20s,10s,5s,1s the employee is paid. I'm sure its just my math that is not working but here is my code

```
       COMPUTE W02-PAY-100S = W02-GROSS-PAY / 100
       COMPUTE PAY = W02-GROSS-PAY - (W02-PAY-100S * 100) 
       COMPUTE W02-PAY-50S = PAY / 50 
       COMPUTE PAY = PAY - (W02-PAY-50S * 50)
       COMPUTE W02-PAY-20S = PAY / 20
       COMPUTE PAY = PAY - (W02-PAY-20S * 20)
       COMPUTE W02-PAY-10S = PAY / 10
       COMPUTE PAY = PAY - (W02-PAY-10S * 10)
       COMPUTE W02-PAY-5S = PAY / 5
       COMPUTE PAY = PAY - (W02-PAY-5S * 5)
       COMPUTE W02-PAY-1S = PAY / 1
       .
```

What ends up happening is the first 100s are displayed as 3, then everything else is 0's.

Comment: You need to show the definitions of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suspect PAY is defined as `PIC 9` rather than `PIC 9(7)` (or whatever), or that there is some problem with the definitions of the other fields you are using (like no integer parts).

However, you're going about it the "wrong" way for COBOL, by making use of the fact that `COMPUTE` is like an assignment statement in other languages.

Instead COBOL offers more nuance with verbs for maths. Have a look at `DIVIDE` with `GIVING` and `REMAINDER`.

```
DIVIDE W02-GROSS-PAY        BY 100
  GIVING                    NOTES-100
  REMAINDER                 W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-100S
DIVIDE W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-100S 
                            BY 50
  GIVING                    NOTES-50
  REMAINDER                 W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-50S
DIVIDE W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-50S 
                            BY 20
  GIVING                    NOTES-20
  REMAINDER                 W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-20S
DIVIDE W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-20S 
                            BY 10
  GIVING                    NOTES-10
  REMAINDER                 W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-10S
DIVIDE W-RUNNING-BALANCE-LESS-10S 
                            BY 05
  GIVING                    NOTES-05
  REMAINDER                 COINS-01
```

If you get your COMPUTEs working, you don't need the last one (divide by one gives you as the answer the original number). With the COMPUTEs you are doing a lot more work than necessary in COBOL.

Now that you know about `DIVIDE`, also look at `MULTIPLY`, `ADD` and `SUBTRACT`.

To complete the picture, look at the intrinsic functions like `INTEGER` and `MOD`. The MOD and more, you have above. The INTEGER is unnecessary because a simple `MOVE` to a field without a fractional part will get there. A MOVE to a field without an integer part will get you the fraction.

Don't, necessarily, look for something which allows you to do it as you would in another language. You may "pass" your COBOL module that way, but you won't really learn COBOL.